# Solr full text search for dynamically added data?

Tags: solr, full-text-search, solrcloud, solr-schema

I'm trying index the data without defining schema.xml, is the any way to apply full text search without adding schema.xml or updating the manged shema?

Answer (score 1):

The default operation mode of Solr is to [use the Schemaless mode](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/schemaless-mode.html). In this mode Solr will guess what the field type is based on what pattern the data matches the first time a field is included. If it is numeric the first time, Solr will guess that it's going to be a numeric field every time.

If the field contains text it'll be indexed as a `text` field with processing applied as defined in the default schema.

As long as you're using the default configuration you can submit documents with just the field name and the associated text, then search against the field name as necessary.practice

Comment: I understood but in case of searching from all fields?

Comment: You can use a `copyField` instruction with source set to `*` and the destination set to one common field like `content` or `text`, then search against that field.